# Use Unicode text or Unicode for string?

Tags: java, string, unicode

I got a problem when save string character.
Example, I create property file for multi language or define a const in .java file. I have 2 options to do it:

```
label.country=Việt Nam

(public static final int COUNTRY = "Việt Nam";)
```

or

```
label.country=\u0056\u0069\u1ec7\u0074 \u004e\u0061\u006d

(public static final int COUNTRY = "\u0056\u0069\u1ec7\u0074 \u004e\u0061\u006d";)
```

I think the first option is no problem, but some people recommend me use second option. I don't know what is the different of that. Please let me know what is the best option and the different between 2 options.

Note: All files are encoded in UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, the first option is recommended.

As long as the file is truly encoded in UTF-8 you are fine. I don't recommend using Unicode escape sequences. The key is that you must tell your java reader that you are reading a UTF-8 file so it can be encoded into UTF-16 Java strings. Something like this:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
           new InputStreamReader(
                      new FileInputStream(fileDir), "UTF8"));
```

If you are writing files to disk and want UTF-8 be sure to set the encoding to UTF8. That is key.

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me when the second option is better?

Comment: The second option, that is escape sequences, are typically used in files which can't themselves be in unicode for whatever reason. For example I have had ASCII source files in java that (long story) could not be saved as UTF-8 or even UTF-16. So within java strings we used Unicode escape characters for foreign language scripts.    It also comes in handy if you wish to encode a Unicode character that cannot be produced via the keyboard such as Unicode Emojis.  I am sure there are plenty of other cases I haven't thought of. Think of escape sequences as a last resort.

Comment: @LinhNguyen ResourceBundles expect property files to be in the ISO-8859-1 encoding.  You can change that, but it requires creating your own ResourceBundle.Control class and implementing a fair amount of logic.